# Error code 12019 / 12007 ajax request on IE8

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-8, timeout, abort

If I disconnect my wifi before sending an ajax request on the IE 10 and FF, the request is aborted. The HTTP status code is 0 and response body is empty.

On IE 8, the response code is 12007 or 12019 and response body is also empty.

I have to have some error handling for aborted requests.

Can I be sure that response code 12007 / 12019 corresponds to aborted request in IE8? Or can it be sent back for other errors?

I see from [MS doc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193625) that this error means:

```
   12019       ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE
               The requested operation cannot be carried out because the
               handle supplied is not in the correct state.

   12007       ERROR_INTERNET_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
               The server name could not be resolved.
```

I just want to be sure that I am correct in thinking that this error is only likely happen when there is n/w failure of some sort.

Comment: I'd really like to know what this error is. It occurs in IE10 and IE11 for a customer of ours. It seems no more requests can be made from the browser after this error occurred. It's an unbearable situation because it clearly happens inside the browser... no request arrives at the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue on IE8 when doing a POST using XmlHttpRequest on a HTTPS URL.

I suspected a SSL certificate issue, thus I entered another URL from the same server in the location address bar, IE notified me about an untrusted certificate. I accepted to browse the URL. Then the POST XHR worked as expected (no HTTP status 12019).

I suppose this is because I another web application on the same server but on a different port and with a different SSL certificate.